# How do I create a basic form in Rails 3 from scratch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

All I want to be able to do is easily create a simple form - that allows me to store info collected from the form in a db, and display it when I go to the controller's show page.

I am a complete Rails n00b, and I have scoured the Rails guides, but they don't quite do it.

They speak generally about forms and how the syntax has changed, but they don't really walk through how to create a simple form (unless I have missed something).

All the tutorials kinda overlook this and roll it into a bigger project - e.g. a shopping cart, or a products catalog or something else like that.

Without using any plugins, how do I accomplish this in rails? I would like to use this exercise to fully understand the interactions between the M, V & C.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered creating a simple scaffold for a model and examining the model, controller and view code it creates? Something like

```
rails g scaffold todo name:string content:text priority:integer
```

should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Actually, just tried this approach. Makes total sense. I can now dissect it and follow the paper trail. Thanks for this suggestion.